# Почему Роспотребнадзор пишется без кавычек?

Tags: кавычки

Почему Роспотребнадзор (Ростех, Роскомнадзор и т. д.) пишется без кавычек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Федеральная служба по надзору в сфере защиты прав потребителей и благополучия человека (**Роспотребнадзор**)
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wikiФедеральная_служба_по_надзору_в_сфере_защиты_прав_потребителей_и_благополучия_человека](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Как правильно употреблять кавычки в аббревиатурных названиях
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/76-kav3

Не заключаются в кавычки сокращенные наименования **органов законодательной и исполнительной власти** (министерств, федеральных агентств, федеральных служб, комитетов и др.), например: Госдума, Мосгордума, **Рособрнадзор**, Центризбирком, Россотрудничество, Минэкономразвития, Москомнаследие.

Наименования **государственных предприятий, учреждений, корпораций, акционерных обществ**, а также крупнейших банков при употреблении без родового слова **испытывают колебания**: Рособоронэкспорт и «Рособоронэкспорт», Роскосмос и «Роскосмос»...

В статье приводится подробная информация по конкретным названиям.